# Samsung S27H850 as external display via USB-C

Tags: display, external-display, usb-c

I think about buying a Samsung S27H850 screen as an external display for my Macbok12 late 2016. I wonder if I can use this screen as an external Monitor via USB-C with a resolution of 2560 x 1440. The Macbok12 does not have a displayPort or HDMI. On the Samsung homepage I read that the USB-C of the screen can be used to charge a device.

Comment: See Page 24 of the .pdf file (support page) __Connection Using the USB Type-C Cable__ ...When a device outputs signals to the monitor using a USB Type-C cable, if the screen is not displayed normally, change the __DP OUT output mode__ (switch the output mode between USB Type-C:MST and USB Type-C:SST)....